Binding a model to a computed property?
I define a model:
const model = defineModel({
    type: String,
});

I define a ref
const query = ref();

I have an input with a v-model of query.
I wish to set model to the value of query, and when the input with v-model="query" is typed in, I wish to update model.
So I do:
model.value = computed(() => {
    return query.value;
});

However, model is not updated. Why?

Just use get/set for a computed query:
Vue SFC Playground
const query = computed({
  get(){
    return model.value
  },
  set(val){
    model.value = val;
  }
});

